# Elastic Search integrate with Spring Boot Web Application

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch

We are planing to implements few search option (Invoice,Inventory,Employee etc) by using Elastic Search. So instead of writing separate API for each search option, gonna make generic search engine.

Can anybody suggest me to refer documentation or tutorial's on integrate with Elastic Search + Spring Boot Web Application

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring has a great example for your task. 
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-data-elasticsearch